# installing processing on sublime and build project

Tags: processing

I am trying to build my processing project on sublmine. i installed processing through package control. when i press ctrl B i get the following error. i also created a new build system and set the build system to it but still getting error. how do i run the program that i wrote?

```html
ERROR: The process "java.exe" not found.
The system cannot find the path specified.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['C://Windows//System32//taskkill.exe', '-f', '-im', 'java.exe', '&', 'C://Program Files//processing-2.0b8//processing-java.exe', '--sketch=E:\\coding', '--output=E:\\coding/build', '--force', '--build', '--run']]
[dir: E:\coding]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin;C:\Users\Melissa12\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin]
```

```html
{
    "shell":true,
    "path": "$file_path//temp",
 "cmd":[
   "C://Windows//System32//taskkill.exe",
   "-f",
   "-im",
   "java.exe",
   "&",
   "C://Program Files//processing-2.0b8//processing-java.exe",
   "--sketch=$file_path",
   "--output=$file_path/build",
   "--force",
   "--build",
   "--run"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Sublime, but it looks like it can't find Java on your PATH variable. That makes sense, because it doesn't look like your PATH contains Java!

Do you have Java installed? Usually it's installed in a place like: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101`

If you don't have it, then first install Java. You probably want the JDK, not the JRE.

Then you have to edit your PATH environment variable so that it includes **the bin directory** inside the Java directory. So using my example above, you'd want to add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin` to your PATH.

Then I would guess that you just need to restart Sublime and it should then be able to find Java.